# LaunchScreen & Splash Screen

Tags: ios, launch-screen

I started remodeling an app I am working on.
I wanted to change its launch screen image

So I went ahead and replaced the images that are in in `LaunchScreen.xib` file

The LaunchScreen.xib file launches the new image but leaves a blank white line where the status bar should be. (this white line is not part of the image)

How can I fix that ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you use auto constraints and use class ?

Comment: You might have given top space to container margin constraint to your image view. Try top space to container.

Comment: Your image view's top constraint contains space between top layout guide of super view.
So you can try change it to space between superview (not top layout guide).

Comment: this line is only visible at runtime

Comment: please post a screenshot of your constraints.

Comment: @SahebRoy please see edit

Comment: @OP this is the constraints on the imageview? i mean you selected the imageview and this is the resultant constraints you geT?

Comment: the previous launch image did not show it, because the image itself was all white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To every strange ios problem, there is an even stranger solution

the solution for me was to set the constraint of the top layout guide to none other than -64...

The reason for it, besides accounting for the 20 pixels of the status bar, i also need to account for the 44 pixels of the navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

Double check your constraints. Or just remove all of them, just to be sure. Then stretch your `UIImageView` so it would take the whole size of the view and add constraints again. Should help.

Comment: redoing the constraints did not help :(